# ValueError: substring not found (using code on Github)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using [this](https://github.com/jpes707/itunes-dl/blob/master/itunes_dl.py) Github repo and getting this error:

```
File "D:\fml.py", line 303, in main
    schema_start_index = album_res.index(schema_start_string)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: substring not found
```

The repo is a script that allows to download albums from apple music, I've already tried changing line 302:
(I replaced name with id because I could actually find that element on the album html page.)

```
schema_start_string = '<script id="schema:music-album" type="application/ld+json">'
```

But I still get the same error, if anyone can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it (:

Comment: as per the error `album_res` does not contain string `schema_start_string`, you can print the value of the `album_res` and check

Comment: Have you considered using a HTML parser like `bs4`?

Comment: Not everything you find on Github is as robust as it might be